# Disable all scripts on the page except for the background javascript of chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I have some page that has a javascript like this:

**some page**

```
<script>
document.location = "http://example.com"
</script>
```

**manifest.js**

```
"content_scripts": [{
     "matches" : ["https://thepage.com/*"],
     "js" : ["background.js"]
}
```

Is there a way to stop the page from redirecting to http://example.com or to disable all scripts in page using the **background.js**??

```
if(redirectingThePage) {
    // stop redirecting and load normally
}
```

Comment: See examples for chrome.contentSettings API to disable javascript execution.

Answer (score 0):

maybe window.stop(). It stops window loading
 [details on MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Window/stop)